# JSON vs multiple connections

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, livesearch

i'm currently building a website which searches an external database and brings up records which match the given search string. The search is live, so results are brought up as the user types.

now the first (and current) approach i took, is that the page actually connects to the mySQL server and retrieves content via AJAX, with EVERY letter the user types in the search box.

now i am starting to look at JSON objects (i only very recently started building websites), and was wondering if it would be a good idea, to load the entire database into a JSON object in the beginning and then look through that when searching.

is this a good idea? would it be faster? thanks in advance

Comment: As an alternative, you can look at caching frequently and recently searched words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends on the size of the data and the complexity of the query. If you can reasonably send the data to the client in advance and then search it locally, then sure, that's useful because it's all local and you don't have the latency of querying the server. But if you have a large amount of data, or the query is complex, it may well make more sense to do the query on the server.

There's no one-size-fits-all solution, it's data-dependent.

> ...and retrieves content via AJAX, with EVERY letter the user types in the search box.

That's usually overkill. Normally, you want to wait until there's a pause in the user's typing before firing off the ajax call, so that if they type "james" in rapid succession, you search for "james" rather than searching for "j", then "ja", then "jam", then "jame", and then "james".

For instance, let's say your search trigger is a `keypress` event. This would be a fairly common approach:

```
var keypressTimer = 0;
function handleKeypress() {
    if (keypressTimer) {
        cancelTimeout(keypressTimer);
    }
    keypressTimer = setTimeout(doSearch, 100); // 100ms = 1/10th of a second
}
function doSearch() {
    var searchValue;

    keypressTimer = 0;
    searchValue = /*...get the search value...*/;
    doAjaxCallUsing(searchValue);
}
```

This is called "debouncing" the input (from hardware engineering, related to the mechanical and electrical "bouncing" of a key as it's pressed).

Comment: sorry, bad wording on my part, i actually do implement a pause with every keyup to actually wait for the user to stop typing :) thanks for the input on the json vs ajax, i might just give it a shot so i can learn more about json objects. cheers!